# Why branch prediction is faster than function call in enum?

Tags: java, enums, jvm, branch-prediction

This is my code. I can totally understand that `benchIfAndSwitch` is faster than `benchSiwtch` because “branch prediction”, but why is `benchEnum` not the fastest one? There is no `if` or `switch` statementtt.

```
public class TestBenchMarks {
    public enum ChannelState {
        CONNECTED, DISCONNECTED, SENT, RECEIVED, CAUGHT
    }

    @State(Scope.Benchmark)
    public static class ExecutionPlan {
        @Param({ "100000" })
        public int size;
        public ChannelState[] states = null;

        public ChannelState2[] states2 = null;

        @Setup
        public void setUp() {
            ChannelState[] values = ChannelState.values();
            states = new ChannelState[size];
            Random random = new Random(new Date().getTime());

            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                int nextInt = random.nextInt(1000000);
                if (nextInt > 100) {
                    states[i] = ChannelState.CONNECTED;
                } else {
                    states[i] = values[nextInt % values.length];
                }
            }

            ChannelState2[] values2 = ChannelState2.values();
            states2 = new ChannelState2[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                if (i > 100) {
                    states2[i] = ChannelState2.CONNECTED;
                } else {
                    states2[i] = values2[i % values2.length];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Fork(value = 5)
    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
    public void benchSiwtch(ExecutionPlan plan, Blackhole bh) {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < plan.size; ++i) {
            switch (plan.states[i]) {
            case CONNECTED:
                result += 1;
                break;
            case DISCONNECTED:
                result += 1;
                break;
            case SENT:
                result += 1;
                break;
            case RECEIVED:
                result += 1;
                break;
            case CAUGHT:
                result += 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        bh.consume(result);
    }

    @Fork(value = 5)
    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
    public void benchIfAndSwitch(ExecutionPlan plan, Blackhole bh) {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < plan.size; ++i) {
            ChannelState state = plan.states[i];
            if (state == ChannelState.CONNECTED) {
                result += 1;
            } else {
                switch (state) {
                case RECEIVED:
                    result += 1;
                    break;
                case SENT:
                    result += 1;
                    break;
                case DISCONNECTED:
                    result += 1;
                    break;
                case CAUGHT:
                    result += 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        bh.consume(result);
    }

    @Fork(value = 5)
    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
    public void benchEnum(ExecutionPlan plan, Blackhole bh) {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < plan.size; ++i) {
            plan.states2[i].handle(result);
        }
        bh.consume(result);
    }


    public enum ChannelState2 {

        /**
         * CONNECTED
         */
        CONNECTED((int a) -> {
            try {
                a = a + 1;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }),

        /**
         * DISCONNECTED
         */
        DISCONNECTED((int a) -> {
            try {
                a = a + 1;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }),

        /**
         * SENT
         */
        SENT((int a) -> {
            try {
                a = a + 1;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }),

        /**
         * RECEIVED
         */
        RECEIVED((int a) -> {
            try {
                a = a + 1;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }),

        /**
         * CAUGHT
         */
        CAUGHT((int a) -> {
            try {
                a = a + 1;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        private final HandlerFunction function;

        ChannelState2(HandlerFunction handleFunction) {
            this.function = handleFunction;
        }

        private void handle(int a) {
            function.handle(a);
        }
    }

    private interface HandlerFunction {
        void handle(int a);
    }
}
```

this is the my result

[image]

and this is my result after remove try-catch from benchEnum

[image]

thanks for everyone's help!!!!!!

Comment: Can you post your benchmark results, so that it is clear how much of a difference there is between the 3 cases. My guess is that you are seeing the overhead of the method call.

Comment: There is an unnecessary try-catch in `ChannelState2`. Also you are using a lambda in `ChannelState2`. Does it make a difference if you leave out the try-catch or implement `handle` per enum value?

Comment: The most obvious difference between `benchEnum()` and the other two is that only `benchEnum()` invokes the `handle()` method of the chosen enum instance.  I have no trouble at all believing that that is less performant than either of the other two.  Overall, however, the whole thing is a bit too synthetic for me.  I don't see the point of these particular benchmarks.

Comment: It’s unlikely to affect the overall performance characteristics in this specific case, but it’s striking that all variants do different things. `benchSiwtch` [sic] always adds one in all branches, `benchIfAndSwitch` effectively does nothing when the value is `ChannelState.CONNECTED`, as `ChannelState.CONNECTED.ordinal()` is zero, and `benchEnum` effectively does nothing at all, as `result` is passed as a parameter to the method which can’t affect the value of `result` in general. Apparently, the JVM could not prove that the methods are side effect free in this specific case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good job on using JMH for this. I do invite you to edit your question and include your benchmark results for future reference.

> but why is benchEnum not the fastest one? There is no if or switch statementtt.

This statement implies that method calls are free relative to some sort of grievous expense incurred by `if` and `switch`.

That's obviously false. In fact, it is quite the opposite! Method calls should be assumed to be an order of magnitude or so (perhaps that's slightly overstating matters) as *more expensive* than an 'if' or 'switch'. Yes, for crucial method calls that aren't inherently doomed to multiple layers of indirection<sup>1</sup>, hotspot will eliminate most of that efficiency, but no matter where you end up, it's not likely to end up being *more efficient* than a switch/if.

In the end, a `switch` / `if`, optimally, at the machine code level, is either literally just a check that fails ('if X is true, jump elsewhere', and X is not true, so the only time that was spent is checking that X is not true), or one that succeeds that results in a single jump. The jump at the end of the `case` block / the `if` body is eliminated because that can just be shortcutted to 'restart the loop that contains this `if`/`switch` construct', which is a cost we're always going to have to pay no matter what we do<sup>2</sup>).

Contrast to a method call, which is, under not-optimal operation here:

- First do a dynamic dispatch lookup to figure out where the *actual code* for `ChannelState2.handle` lives. This requires scanning a lookup table that links method signatures for the specific type to the place the actual code that contains its implementation lives. That's one expensive lookup + 1 jump.
- Then execute the code in `handle` which... immediately needs to grab the contents of a field (field `function`), do a dynamic dispatch on *that* to find out where the code for its `apply` function lives, and then jump *there*. That's a field fetch + an expensive lookup + a jump.

That's.. a lot. Hotspot can easily eliminate that first expensive lookup because enums are final. It can even eliminate that first jump via inlining. But that field fetch + expensive lookup + jump inherent in calling the lambda function is a lot more difficult. The expensive lookup part in particular is hard to eliminate here.

'expensive' is a relative term. It's not usually so expensive that it's a concern. However, you're comparing it to the time taken by the `JMP` instructions caused by hopping through a switch block which are infinitesemal. In contrast to *that* tiny cost, invoking a methodhandle (which is what code is going to end up running as) is much more expensive.

It's not surprising at all that the method-call based one is slower than the others. The others end up invoking `.ordinal()` in the bytecode, but hotspot can eliminate that and probably is, which means those switches end up being a literal 'depending on the number value of this word sized block, jump to one of a few disparate code blocks' which requires no visits to memory whatsoever.

---

[1] Imagine a method that accepts, say, a `java.util.List` and ends up invoking `.get()` on this argument, but you call this method repeatedly handing it instances of a cavalcade of different actual types (List is an interface, the object you hand to this method must therefore be an instance of some subtype of it), each type having a different `get` implementation. Here the system is going to have to somehow do some sort of lookup somewhere to figure out which `get` method to call, because there are loads of different ones. That's what I mean with 'doomed to a layer of indirection' - it's *intrinsic* to this code flow and thus a hotspot compilation step can't eliminate it. In contrast, if every call you hand an instance of `ArrayList` (and not some subtype of it, or at least not something that overrides `get`), then that *can* be optimized. Not at first; `ArrayList` is not final after all, but a hotspot compiler can, and generally will, use presumptive compilation: It will **assume** that you are always going to hand it an ArrayList instance and will take the layer of indirection out, jumping directly to `ArrayList`'s `get` method, and will add some bells and whistles to the system so that if you ever hand something else, the presumptively hotspotted code path is invalidated (because it was designed to presume an assumption that has now ceased to be true, thus, the code is no longer valid). This is how hotspot is meant to work: Make assumptions based on observed behaviour and simply invalidate the hotspotted code if one of the assumptions fails; assuming that code is still in the 'hot path' it'll be hotspotted again, now with more information, soon.

[2] There's loop unrolling, but, that doesn't apply here, you're looping far too often. The existence of these constructs mostly eliminate loop unroll as an option.

Comment: Your comparison with `java.util.List` might be too far off for this specific case, because the `handle` method is invoked on elements of a typed array and that method is effectively final.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker I explain that those parts are easily hotspotted out, but then focus on the layer of indirection inherent in the invocation of the `handlerFunction` field in the enum, where it is _very_ apt.